# How to bind the last 12 months in a dropdown list in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a dropdown list in my web application, I need to be able to bind the last 12 months in proper order in it. Suppose its February 2016 now, so the dropdown list must show March followed by April, May, June .... upto January.

```
<label>Select Month</label>
<select id = "drp1" onchange="mnth=this.value; drawChart1();">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

I want the values in proper order on page load. I cannot figure out which Javascript function will be able to do this, or how can I bind values to a JSON and use it to make the options in the dropdown. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: A `Date` object ? `getMonth()` ? `for-loop` ?

Comment: Is it not sufficient to have the current month selected?

Comment: do you want to get bind on page load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `new Date()` will return current Date object.

`DateObj.getMonth()` will return `month` from the Date object(0-11)

You can create options dynamically like this:

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
var months = 12;
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var select = document.getElementById('drp1');
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < months; i++) {
  var m = date.getMonth();
  html += '<option value="' + monthNames[m] + '">' + monthNames[m] + '</option>'
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
}
select.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<select id="drp1"></select>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/njevo64e/2/)

Comment: Thank You for the code snippet and fiddle. It worked for me